# Stuck on twitter redirect page when trying to save credentials

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

I'm using the twitter-api-v2 package and I cant save my `access_token`, `access_token_secret` and `oauth_verifier`. i want to save the `oauth_verifier` because i want to create the actual bot in another file.

Here's what I've found

- Using writeFile throws me the error in my catch statement
- Using writeFileSync keeps me stuck on the page, and does not write to the file
- Trying to tweet something works, the tweet *is* sent in the background, but i *stay stuck* on the page

```js
client
    .login(oauth_verifier)
    .then(({ client: loggedClient, accessToken, accessSecret }) => {
      let tokens = {
        accessToken: accessToken,
        accessSecret: accessSecret,
      };
      fs.writeFile("./tokens.json", JSON.stringify(tokens));
      // loggedClient.v2.tweet("hello this is test number: 3"); << this works. i stay stuck
                                                              //on the redirect page, but the tweet is sent
    })
    .catch(() => res.status(403).send("Invalid verifier or access tokens!"));
```

I was able to save my `access_token` and `access_token_secret` the first time i ran this code. but I cannot anymore.

I will also add, to clear any confusion, i am not providing a service. This is a bot that i am creating to practice, and i am not providing a servce. if that is relevant.

Comment: What are the exact errors you get? And did you check you get the 'accessToken' and 'accessSecret' as expected?

Comment: @RonHillel as i said, if i use writeFile(), i get the error in my .catch() method which is error 403 i also get a 404 error but i believe that's a favicon error. if i use writeFileSync() i stay stuck on the redirect page. 

The first time i ran the script, i did get correct `accessToken` and `accessSecret`, (at least i think i did, i cant check them now, but i'm pretty sure i did receive the correct credentials)

Comment: Can you use 'writeFile' or 'writeFileSync' without any errors outside the twitter request? (To verify it works)

Comment: Hello @RonHillel i can use `writeFile` and `writeFileSync` without any issues if i execute it outside of my callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issue has been resolved.
Turns out, the problem was that i was not sending a success response to twitter.
I just needed to send a 200 status response in my `.then()` where i write to my json file.